# Is There event of autocmd in vim triggered by inputing character exceeding the specified column number?

Tags: vim

Is There event of `autocmd` in `vim` triggered by  inputing beyond specify column  ? 
I can't find the event I need.
If the event doesn't exist, can I customize event of `autocmd`?
I want to execute a command  When my input character exceeds the specified column number.

This command `:match Underlined /.\%>81v/` can specify style of characters beyond `81`, and now I want to run command instead of changing style.

Comment: oh, I try it myself and it works finally although it may be not efficient.

Comment: example: autocmd CursorMovedI * if col('.') == 82|exec "MyFun"|endif

Comment: What kind of function do you want to run?

Comment: such as "normal! gww" , but it seems a little bit of a problem that the cursor position. So my function finally become: `if (getline('.')[col('.')-1] != "") exec "normal! gwwa \<esc>" else exec "normal! gwwa" endif`

Comment: The condition is a space instead of "" , I typed wrong above comment.

Comment: How stupid I am,  there is existing method: `:set textwidth=80 :set formatoptions+=t`. And I didn't tell the main purpose in my question.Foolish!

Answer (score 2):

The `CursorMovedI` event is triggered in *insert mode* whenever the cursor moves (due to typing, movement, etc.) The current screen column can be queried via `virtcol('.')`; the `col('.')` function returns the *byte index*, which is different when there are tabs, double-width characters, or any non-ASCII character.
So, you can trigger a custom function via

```
:autocmd CursorMovedI * if virtcol('.') > 80 | ... | endif
```

However, if you're just after automatically inserting a linebreak after a certain column, that functionality is built in. See `:help 'textwidth'` (alternatively `'wrapmargin'`) and `:help fo-table`. The following will break text after 80 columns:

```
:set textwidth=80 formatoptions+=t
```